# laravel eloquent custom computation on the fly

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question on DB query. Currently I'm doing the following paginate :

```
$permissions = Product_permission::groupBy("societe_id")->paginate(15);
```

***`Product_permission`*** has a column ***`access`*** with following values *`(web, form, api)`*.

I would like to create a weight variable in the query which is a weighted as follow *`(web = 1, form = 2, api = 3)`* and sort the sum group by *`societe_id`* *`desc`*.

Do you know how?

Comment: I think there are better solutions on design... you could use three columns... or you could use a hasMany table/relation... or even a table to store the valid values and a pivot table... if you really need this structure... do it on laravel/php side...

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: the access column contain a string "web,form,api" or `id:1 access:web` and `id:2 access:form` ?

Comment: One row by access ie id:1 access:web and id:2 access:form

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$permissions = Product_permission::groupBy("societe_id")->paginate(15);

foreach($permission as $permission){

    $auxArr = explode(",", $permission->access);

    $auxCount = 0;
    foreach($auxArr as $access_col_value)
    if($access_col_value == 'web'){
        $auxCount += 1;
    }else if($access_col_value == 'form'){
        $auxCount += 2;
    }else if($access_col_value == 'api'){
        $auxCount += 3;
    }

    $permission->acces_col_sum = $auxCount;

}
```

---

If you want it on eloquent... you'll have to add a selectRaw with a CASE inside, and add every possible permutation and its value like:

```
CASE WHEN access = 'web,form,api' OR access = 'api,form,web'....
```

UNLESS YOU are sure this always have the same order i would not recommend it...